# ormlite - no field annotation in the case of object array reference

Tags: android, ormlite

I am using ormlite 4.46.

I am getting error, "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No fields have a DatabaseField annotation in class [xx.xx.xx]" for the following scenario,

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName="AClass") 
class A{ 
      @DatabaseField(generatedId = true, columnName = "_id")      
      private int id;

      @DatabaseField(foreign = true, foreignAutoCreate = true, canBeNull = true, foreignAutoRefresh = true) 
      @JsonProperty("bproperty")
      private B[] bObjects;

    }     

     @DatabaseTable(tableName="BClass")
     class B{
          @DatabaseField(generatedId = true, columnName = "_id")      
          private int id;
      }
```

any idea on how we handle this scenario ?

Thanks in advance,

JRH

Answer (score 0):

> I am getting error, "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No fields have a DatabaseField annotation in class [xx.xx.xx]" for the following scenario,

I don't quite understand why this error is shown.  It might be that the database table configuration file was not properly generated?  It might have thrown an exception because you cannot persist  arrays of elements using ORMLite.

Can you try regenerating your database table config file and watch for exceptions?